# X-UA-Compatible in two different pools does not work

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, iis-7, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem in a project that was developed some years ago. Now with IE 10, there are some links, buttons and images dont work.
One way to solve the problem was to put the IIS HTTP Custom Header "**X-UA-Compatible IE = edge**".

So far so good. It worked correctly in IIS Web site, however, if i do the same to another site, does not work with IE 10.
Does anyone know where can be the problem? Did file comparison, saw the web.config, is practically equal. On site works, another does not.

Comment: "some years ago" ? could it be this issue ? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx ?

Comment: @jbl i tried the Machine-wide fixes but continues the problem.